# secure microprofile REST client with OAuth2 / OIDC

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, cxf, openid-connect, microprofile

I'm using [Apache CXF](https://cxf.apache.org/) to access JAX-RS services. Authenticating users is done through [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) (OpenID Connect/OAuth2).
The `BearerAuthSupplier` is automatically handling `refreshTokens` and receives new `accessTokens`.
But how do I handle the case when a session is expired or logged-out (e.g logout by admin) and receiving a 401 error?
I'm guessing there must be a way to provide the credentials which then are used to do a new login, before doing the actual service call.

```
String serverUrl = "http://localhost:8180/auth";
String realm = "share-server";
String clientId = "share-server-service-login";
String clientSecret = "e70752a6-8910-4043-8926-03661f43398c";
String username = "test";
String password = "test";

String tokenUri = serverUrl + "/realms/" + realm + "/protocol/openid-connect/token";

Consumer consumer = new Consumer(clientId);

ResourceOwnerGrant grant = new ResourceOwnerGrant(username, password);
ClientAccessToken initial = OAuthClientUtils.getAccessToken(tokenUri, consumer, grant, true);

BearerAuthSupplier supplier = new BearerAuthSupplier();
supplier.setAccessToken(initial.getTokenKey());
supplier.setRefreshToken(initial.getRefreshToken());
supplier.setConsumer(consumer);
supplier.setAccessTokenServiceUri(tokenUri);

HTTPConduitConfigurer httpConduitConfigurer = new HTTPConduitConfigurer() {
    @Override
    public void configure(String name, String address, HTTPConduit c) {
        c.setAuthSupplier(supplier);
    }
};

Bus bus = BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus();
bus.setExtension(httpConduitConfigurer, HTTPConduitConfigurer.class);

URI apiUri = new URI("http://localhost:8080/services/");
RestClientBuilder client = new CxfTypeSafeClientBuilder().baseUri(apiUri);

IDemoService service = client.build(IDemoService.class);
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    System.out.println("client: " + new Date() + " " + service.test());
    Thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000);
}
```

> javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized

```
WARNUNG: Interceptor for {http://service.server.share.scodi.ch/}IDemoService has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.provider.OAuthServiceException: OAuthServiceException invoking http://localhost:8080/services/demo/test: OAuthError[error='invalid_grant', errorDescription='Session not active', errorUri='null']
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1400)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1389)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.close(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:77)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:671)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:63)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.doRunInterceptorChain(AbstractClient.java:701)
    at org.apache.cxf.microprofile.client.proxy.MicroProfileClientProxyImpl.doRunInterceptorChain(MicroProfileClientProxyImpl.java:165)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.doChainedInvocation(ClientProxyImpl.java:899)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.invoke(ClientProxyImpl.java:345)
    at org.apache.cxf.microprofile.client.proxy.MicroProfileClientProxyImpl.invokeActual(MicroProfileClientProxyImpl.java:439)
    at org.apache.cxf.microprofile.client.proxy.MicroProfileClientProxyImpl.access$000(MicroProfileClientProxyImpl.java:70)
    at org.apache.cxf.microprofile.client.proxy.MicroProfileClientProxyImpl$Invoker.call(MicroProfileClientProxyImpl.java:458)
    at org.apache.cxf.microprofile.client.cdi.CDIInterceptorWrapper$BasicCDIInterceptorWrapper.invoke(CDIInterceptorWrapper.java:43)
    at org.apache.cxf.microprofile.client.proxy.MicroProfileClientProxyImpl.invoke(MicroProfileClientProxyImpl.java:435)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.test(Unknown Source)
    at ch.scodi.share.server.ClientTest.main(ClientTest.java:78)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.provider.OAuthServiceException: OAuthError[error='invalid_grant', errorDescription='Session not active', errorUri='null']
    at org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.client.OAuthClientUtils.getAccessToken(OAuthClientUtils.java:321)
    at org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.client.OAuthClientUtils.refreshAccessToken(OAuthClientUtils.java:244)
    at org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.client.OAuthClientUtils.refreshAccessToken(OAuthClientUtils.java:235)
    at org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.client.BearerAuthSupplier.refreshAccessToken(BearerAuthSupplier.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.client.BearerAuthSupplier.getAuthorization(BearerAuthSupplier.java:63)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.authorizationRetransmit(HTTPConduit.java:1529)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.processRetransmit(HTTPConduit.java:1461)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleRetransmits(HTTPConduit.java:1435)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1565)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1371)
    ... 16 more
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized
    at org.apache.cxf.microprofile.client.DefaultResponseExceptionMapper.toThrowable(DefaultResponseExceptionMapper.java:33)
    at org.apache.cxf.microprofile.client.proxy.MicroProfileClientProxyImpl.checkResponse(MicroProfileClientProxyImpl.java:183)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.handleResponse(ClientProxyImpl.java:1002)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.doChainedInvocation(ClientProxyImpl.java:907)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.invoke(ClientProxyImpl.java:345)
    at org.apache.cxf.microprofile.client.proxy.MicroProfileClientProxyImpl.invokeActual(MicroProfileClientProxyImpl.java:439)
    at org.apache.cxf.microprofile.client.proxy.MicroProfileClientProxyImpl.access$000(MicroProfileClientProxyImpl.java:70)
    at org.apache.cxf.microprofile.client.proxy.MicroProfileClientProxyImpl$Invoker.call(MicroProfileClientProxyImpl.java:458)
    at org.apache.cxf.microprofile.client.cdi.CDIInterceptorWrapper$BasicCDIInterceptorWrapper.invoke(CDIInterceptorWrapper.java:43)
    at org.apache.cxf.microprofile.client.proxy.MicroProfileClientProxyImpl.invoke(MicroProfileClientProxyImpl.java:435)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.test(Unknown Source)
    at ch.scodi.share.server.ClientTest.main(ClientTest.java:78)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solutions I came up with, do a login for the following use cases:

- initial login
- refresh token expired
- session expired (Stale token)
- session was logged-out (manually, service-restart)
- other OAuthServiceException is thrown during authorization

---

```
String serverUrl = "http://localhost:8180/auth";
String realm = "share-server";
String clientId = "share-server-service-login";
String clientSecret = "e70752a6-8910-4043-8926-03661f43398c";
String username = "test";
String password = "test";

String tokenUri = serverUrl + "/realms/" + realm + "/protocol/openid-connect/token";

ResourceOwnerGrant grant = new ResourceOwnerGrant(username, password);
AuthSupplier supplier = new AuthSupplier(tokenUri, clientId, clientSecret, grant);
HTTPConduitConfigurer httpConduitConfigurer = new HTTPConduitConfigurer() {
    @Override
    public void configure(String name, String address, HTTPConduit c) {
        // don't do authentication on token URI
        if (!tokenUri.equals(address)) {
            c.setAuthSupplier(supplier);
        }
    }
};

Bus bus = BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus();
bus.setExtension(httpConduitConfigurer, HTTPConduitConfigurer.class);

... REST-Client Code ...
```

---

```
public static class AuthSupplier extends BearerAuthSupplier {

    private WebClient webClient = null;
    private AccessTokenGrant grant;

    public AuthSupplier(String tokenUri, String clientId, String clientSecret, AccessTokenGrant grant) {
        grant = grant;
        webClient = WebClient.create(tokenUri);
        setAccessTokenServiceUri(tokenUri);
        setConsumer(new Consumer(clientId, clientSecret));
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthorization(AuthorizationPolicy authPolicy, URI currentURI, Message message, String fullHeader) {
        String authorization = null;
        try {
            authorization = super.getAuthorization(authPolicy, currentURI, message, fullHeader);
        } catch (OAuthServiceException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getError().getState() + " " + e.getMessage());
        }

        if (authorization == null) {
            // refresh token expired or session expired (Stale token) or session was logged-out (manually, service-restart), do new login
            login();

            // try to get authorization again after login
            authorization = super.getAuthorization(authPolicy, currentURI, message, null);
        }
        return authorization;
    }

    private void login() {
        ClientAccessToken accessToken = OAuthClientUtils.getAccessToken(webClient, getConsumer(), grant, false);
        setAccessToken(accessToken.getTokenKey());
        setRefreshToken(accessToken.getRefreshToken());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

OAuth clients should always be written to check for 401 responses when calling an API, and to refresh the token and retry the API request with the new token if possible, or trigger re-authentication otherwise.

I tend to manage this via 2 classes as follows:

- [API client](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/spa/src/api/client/apiClient.ts)
- [OAuth Client](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts)

The above example is for a Web UI but can be written for any OAuth client flow or tech stack.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do but I didn't find a proper way with the Apache CXF client.

Comment: If dealing with direct HTTP calls, the flow can be directly translated between languages, but in this case, OP is talking about specifically JAX-RS and Apache CXF. JAX-RS is a standard Java API that "hides" all the flow behind curtains, and uses filters and interceptors to deal with everything so you can isolate all the REST-related code, and CXF has an implementation/extension for JAX-RS. There's no way to translate the flow between different APIs with different paradigms and approaches if you don't know how to do this and that in the new API, and that's what the question is about...